# Which mobile application framework is good to build a mobile map navigation app

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I want to develop a navigation app just like Uber/Ola for one of our client. I was searching for hybrid/native platforms and i found **Map box** which have its own in build map navigation system. It can support iOS and android native platform but am not sure about hybrid platform like **React Native,Flutter** etc. Personally I was thinking to go with using react native.

Answer (score 0):

[Leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) is easier to learn and completely free, (unlike map box). It is easy to learn, well documented, well supported and there are plenty of examples.

These links show that it will integrate with no problem with [React Native](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) & [Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map).